# How to hide the category block in navigation on all pages if the user is not a login

Tags: magento2, php, category, access

How to hide the category block in navigation on all pages if the user is not a login?
[image]

Also, if a user tries to navigate to a category via a link, it should be redirected to the login page.

Comment: do you want to hide category from header menu ??

Comment: @Hiren Yes, and restrict access to them if the transition is through a direct link. If the transition is redirected to the login page

Comment: You can do this by event observer.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect not login customer when category page is load either by URL, you can do this one.

1. create `events.xml` file at the following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Exxtension\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_controller_category_init_after">
        <observer name="restrict_category_load" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\CategoryRestrictObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

2. Now create `CategoryRestrictObserver.php` file at the following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Exxtension\Observer\CategoryRestrictObserver.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

class CategoryRestrictObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Check If customer is not login, then redirect on login page
    }
}
```